# How to identify the same user between windows server active directory and azure AD?

Tags: windows, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have an asp.net MVC web application, which is migrated from Windows authentication to Azure AD authentication.

On windows authentication, this.User.Identity.Name on controller returns domain\alias,
and on Azure Ad authentication, it returns alias@xxx.com.

The problem is sometimes, users' domain, alias or email may change. So which parameter can be used to identify the same user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So which parameter can be used to identify the same user?

I think I understood your explanation. If I understand it correctly: Maybe we can use `UserPrincipalName` to identify the same user.

Azure Active Directory schema does **not allow** two of more objects to have the same value of the following attributes(This is not an exhaustive list.). That is each object in Azure AD is forced to have a unique value of these attributes at a given instance.

```
ProxyAddresses
UserPrincipalName
onPremisesSecurityIdentifier
ObjectId
```

Comment: Just want to confirm the current situations.

Please feel free to let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: It's helpful. Some users have their domain changed, in windows authentication, it treated as different users. but in Azure AD, they are shared same email address(same user), we have to handle them as special case.

Comment: Are there some attributes which can be used to be 1 to 1 map between windows AD and Azure AD?

Comment: @L.W By default, we use Azure AD connect to sync users from on-prem to Azure AD, if we change our information from on-prem, Azure AD will change too, so we just should set the right sync rules, and monitor the sync jobs, so it will work fine. More information about Azure AD sync rules, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-configure-filtering).